# Prove or disprove that $|a_1|+|a_2|+\ldots+|a_n|\leq n\sqrt{a_1^2+\ldots+a_n^2}$, by showing that $RHS-LHS\geq 0$ if possible.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, radicals, fractions, absolute-value

Prove or disprove that $$\left|a_1\right|+\left|a_2\right|+\ldots+\left|a_n\right|\leq n\sqrt{a_1^2+\ldots+a_n^2}$$

Where $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

EDIT: I was hoping there is a way without using a known inequality, ie to prove that $RHS-LHS\geq 0$

Comment: A much stronger result is immediate from a certain well known inequality. Hint: $a_n=1\cdot a_n$.

Comment: I.e., you can replace $n$ by $\sqrt{n}$, this will still be true (and might give you an idea about where it comes from).

Comment: what if i don't want use the mean inequality, is there a way to tell that the $RHS-LHS\geq 0$?

Comment: "Cauchy-Schwarz"?

Comment: We can also use holder's inequality here

Comment: In this setting, wouldn't Holder be exactly CS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that $|a_i|^2=a_i^2$. Using the [Generalized Mean Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean), we see $$\frac{|a_1|+\cdots+|a_n|}{n}\leq \sqrt{\frac{|a_1|^2+\cdots+|a_n|^2}{n}}$$
which we can rewrite to
$$|a_1|+\cdots+|a_n|\leq \sqrt{n}\sqrt{a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2}$$
and since $\sqrt{n}\leq n$ we get $$|a_1|+\cdots+|a_n|\leq n\sqrt{a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2}$$

---

Alternatively, we can use [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality):
$$(|a_1|\cdot |1|+\cdots |a_n|\cdot |1|)^2\leq (|a_1|^2+\cdots |a_n|^2)(|1|^2+\cdots+|1|^2)$$ which we can also rewrite to $$|a_1|+\cdots+|a_n|\leq \sqrt{n}\sqrt{a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2}$$ and finishing the proof the same way.

Comment: Yes, I realized. I added it as alternative proof

Comment: in the 2nd step, It is not clear what happened to $n*sqrt(\frac{1}{n})$ on the R.H.S.

Comment: @NoChance You multiply both sides by $n$: the factor in the LHS becomes 1, the one in the RHS becomes $n\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} = \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Clear now thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean $RHS=\sqrt{n(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)}$.

If so we have:

$RHS-LHS=\frac{\sum\limits_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\left(|a_i|-|a_j|\right)^2}{RHS+LHS}\geq0$, which you wished.